# How to handle shared data between the controller and the view in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

We have a model (say, `List<string>`). The function that builds the list is non-deterministic and the output is needed to be referenced in both controller and the view during the lifetime of the request. Since it's per-request, it cannot be static or singleton.

It's a common structure and it can be referenced from any view or controller.

Since we can't access controller from the view (by principle, and we agree), we cannot keep it in the controller. We're currently keeping it in the `ViewData` dictionary and initialize it in the controller, or the view (if the controller didn't need it).

We think that using `ViewData` for this purpose may not be ideal since it's not created to be consumed by a controller in the first place. Is there a better way to share common per-request data between Controller and the View? If not we'll stick with `ViewData`.

There is `HttpContext.Items` dictionary but I'm not sure if it fits to this purpose.

Comment: "There is HttpContext.Items dictionary but I'm not sure if it fits to this purpose." - it fits. Use that.

Comment: "initialize it in a view or a controller, whichever runs first." - how can a view run before the controller???

Comment: actually AFAIK ViewData *is* HttpContext.Current.Items under the hood. And since when is "ViewData created to be consumed by a controller"? It's consumed by the *View*, where the data is *provided* by the Controller.

Comment: @Developer Art: There is a chance that it may not be run in controller at all. Then, view initializes it when referencing. yes there isn't a chance for the controller code to run after the view.

Comment: RPM1984: That's what I said? Quoting myself: "since it's not created to be consumed by a controller in the first place"

Comment: of course by consuming I mean "relying on the contents of for proper operation"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the output is needed to be referenced in both controller and the view during the lifetime of the request

The way MVC works, the Action code in the Controller is executed, and the resulting data is passed to the view engine that draws the page using the info you passed either with the call to View(data) or in the ViewData dictionary.

I don't know what you are trying to do, but it sounds like it's more a problem of a bad approach than a technical one (I might be wrong, though).

Could you explain why you need the controller while the View is rendered? If you need any logic associated with the List (to process it or do anything with it) I would just create a new class that extends List<T>, add the logic to that class instead of the controller, and pass an object of that class to the View, either using View() or ViewData[].

Comment: Simple, I need the same data for both rendering decisions and controller logic, such as `OnActionExecuting`. But I can't retrieve it twice from the service as it modifies the data.

Comment: Mmmm... I think I'm starting to understand what you are trying to do. If I got it correctly, I would extend the controller class with a new one that contained the property you want to share within the actions, events, and attributes of the controller, and send that property to the View using ViewData[].

Comment: Yeah that made sense to me too. However there is a high chance that controller doesn't need that data at all. And if both controller and view doesn't reference it we shouldn't be calling the service (aka lazy initialization). That's why we're not initializing in controller always.

Comment: As you mention, use lazy initialization. Declare both a public and private property (ex. Property and _property). The getter of the public property should check if the private one is null. If it's null, call the service, store the returned data in the private property, and return it. If it isn't null, just return the private property. Except in the getter, use always the public property to access the value. With this approach, the service will be called only once, if needed.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because I agree with the point that the approach itself is suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

Controller action should always be called be first. If you have multiple controllers calling the same view/partial view then you should be refactoring the code to one method and call that.

ViewData is the solution to do this, if your really wanting "once access" type information then maybe TempData but ViewData is designed for this.

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify that controller didn't run after the view. It's just that controller may not access the data at all and then it becomes view's responsibility to build it.

Comment: Not my answer, my question :)

Answer (score 0):

What is exact thing you're trying to do?

Seems like you just asking about the way to pass some data from the Controller to the View which is rather trivial task. Just use ViewData, yes, or ViewBag in MVC3 case or use ViewModels.

Or there is somewhat special case? What does "referencing from Controller and from View" mean? Where the data is coming from? Usually the case is that Controller prepares data for the View and passes it as an ActionResult (or better, as a ViewModel). View should never take some data on its own bypassing the controller.

Comment: Vasilio thanks for your interest but this better fits to a comment, not an answer :) I have a service class that provides a piece of data. This data takes time to produce and it's not possible to produce it twice. Therefore I need to pull it only once. However the data may be used in both a Controller and the View. I'm already building it "on demand", so I'm trying to figure out where to place it.

Comment: Well, as you can see I'm just started to use this site. And unfortunately it doesn't let me add comments, only answers are allowed. Not sure why they made it this way but its SO business so I don't pretend :)

Comment: As for the question: Why the Controller should ever know something initiated by View? Controller generally prepares all the data for the View no matter where the data is originated (Repos, Services and so on). If your Controller needs data from View in single request it is possibly the reason to review your architecture. Anyway more specific tasks details would be helpful in order to provide correct answer.

Comment: You have a point there but think of "deciding on which view to return, or where to redirect" and think that the afromentioned decision depends on the data. (And views use it for rendering).

Comment: ssg, well I read some other comments above and have to say: I'm not sure about how you're going to instantiate View bypassing the Controller at all and moreover - don't see any real-world examples when I need that. You can easily decide on what View to use by creating your own ViewResult and a set of conventions based on provided data (data may be created somewhere else not only Controller, but anyway the View is definitely last-man to appear in sequence of execution). You may use HttpContext.Items from anywhere but it seems like somewhat a hack for me (and makes you dependent on HttpContext)